# Finding if there are inserted rows in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

In PHP I will like to know if there were inserted records.
Here is my code:

```
$SQL = "Insert INTO #TestTable(F1,F2) Select data1, data2 From MyTable";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL);
$rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt);
```

If I inserted 2 records into `#TestTable` I will like `$rows` to be true, but is not that way. `$rows` is always false.
I don't care how many rows were inserted. I just want to know if there were rows inserted.

Comment: Try using **sqlsrv_rows_affected()**

Comment: You are right, thank you